# mod_rewrite not rewriting url

Tags: mod-rewrite

What's the reason why something like this doesn't seem to work:

php file: display.php (it's an empty file)

.htaccess has the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ display.php?country=$1&state=$2&city=$3 [L]
```

when I try:

```
http://somewebsite.com/display.php?country=USA&state=Minnesota&city=Minneapolis
```

it does NOT re-write it as

```
http://somewebsite.com/USA/Minnesota/Minneapolis
```

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm just not parsing your question correctly, or if it's really unclear what you're asking.  Are you trying to take the URL `.../display.php?...` and rewrite it as `/USA/Minnesota/Minneapolis`?  Or are you trying to rewrite `/USA/Minnesota/Minneapolis` as `.../display.php?...`?  Your rewrite rule is going one direction and it sounds like you're typing the other.

Comment: essentially, I'm just trying to rewrite url: from something like display.php?country=USA&state=Minnesota&city=Minneapolis to simply USA/Minnesota/Minneapolis/

Comment: I think you need to go back and understand what you are trying to ask: mod_rewrite interprets an URL differently, or it helps to you redirect your URL into a different destination. I think you need to clarify the problem by understanding what is the input and what is the outcome. And ask the question from the user's perspective, what do you want to see the application do

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to rewrite from:

```
http://somewebsite.com/display.php?country=USA&state=Minnesota&city=Minneapolis
```

to:

```
http://somewebsite.com/USA/Minnesota/Minneapolis
```

Then your rewrite rule is backwards - [the format for `RewriteRule` lines](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is:

```
RewriteRule <pattern to match> <substitution>
```

Thus, you would want the *pattern to match* to refer to `/display.php...` and the *substitution* to be the new URI `/country/state/city`.  In addition, you'll need to use the `RewriteCond` conditional to match the query string.  Your rule will need to look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=([a-zA-Z]+)&state=([a-zA-Z]+)&city=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^/display.php$ /%1/%2/%3? [R]
```

(Note the trailing `?` at the end of `RewriteRule` - this indicates that the query string should be removed.  Without the trailing `?`, you would get the query string repeated.)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing forward slash in target url.